# Spring Boot REST API display response results in the format

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, kotti

I want to display the response result in the following format:

```
[
"author":"Author",
"status_code":"200"
"message":"GET",
"description":"Description..."
"data":{
    "id":"123",
    "name":""My Name",
    ...   : ...
}
]
```

But I only display each data result as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id":"123",
    "name":""My Name",
    ...   : ...
  }
]
```

**This is the code snippet that displays the response   result**

- **Controller**

```
 @GetMapping(value = "categorie")
    fun getAllFoodCategories(@Param(value = "key") key:String): ResponseEntity<List<Category>> {

        if (key==AppUtils.APY_KEY){
            var foodCategories: List<Category> = foodCategoryRespository.findAll()
            return if(!foodCategories.isEmpty()){
                foodCategories.forEach { v ->
                    run {
                        logger.info(v.toString())
                    }
                }
                ResponseEntity(foodCategories, HttpStatus.OK)
            }else{
                ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
            }

        }else{
            return ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
        }
        
    }
```

- **The model class**

```
@Entity(name = "categories")
data class Category(
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        val id: Int,
        @get: NotBlank
        @Column(name = "name")
        val name: String
)
```

Can someone help me with the answer, Thanks you.

Comment: Can you provide the `Category` class?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for the response format to be **JSON**?

Comment: Since you are returning a `List<Category>`, where did you expect the `author`, `status_code`, etc. fields/values to *magically* come from?

Comment: @zlaval I update class Category,please review help me

Comment: @Andreas Yep, I think I want to display the json form like the first code snippet,

Comment: @Thang The first code snippet, the one with `"author":"Author"`, is not JSON, because you can't have `"name":"value"` pairs inside an `[ ]` array, only inside an `{ }` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return different elements as a list, but you can return as an object, which contains a list of category. Like this:

```
{
"author":"Author",
"status_code":"200"
"message":"GET",
"description":"Description..."
"data":[
    {
        "id":"123",
        "name":""My Name",
        ...   : ...
    }
 ]
}
```

For this, create a model like:

```
data class MyResponse(
   val author: String,
   val statusCode: String,
   val message: String,
   val description: String,
   val data: List<Category>
)
```

Then return with:

```
fun getAllFoodCategories(@Param(value = "key") key:String): ResponseEntity<MyResponse> {...}
```